# Play RTSP streaming in an Android application, The live is coming back

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, rtsp, sdp

I'm doing an android app that plays video from live camera.
I can watch live, but it comes back 1.5 seconds. 
We do not want.

I used standard settings:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView videoView;
    String videoUrl = "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.125/live/0/h264.sdp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.rtspVideo);
        RtspStream(videoUrl);
    }

    private void RtspStream(String rtspUrl) {
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(rtspUrl));
        videoView.setZOrderOnTop(false);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.postInvalidateDelayed(0);
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

I think it's about buffer.

How can I solve the problem of coming back?

how can the library or application settings be used?

Comment: you mean to say that there is 1.5 seconds delay?

Comment: live broadcast comes late on screen.my movements are after 1.5 seconds looks.

Comment: Use VLC instead Video view.
Here is an example https://github.com/Truiton/RTMPPlayer